# How to run control animation inside Template by ViewModel property change

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, maui, .net-maui

.Net Maui page with `CarouselView` and list of cards created via data binding to the collection of items in ViewModel (VM). I'm looking for ways to animate control inside `CarouselView` by some property in VM set to a particular value. Animation should be done in c# code (code-behind, trigger action, behavior etc.), not by xaml. Not sure how to properly implement that. This is what I considered as possible solutions:

- Declare event in VM and subscribe for it in code-behind. Works very well for non-template controls, but with `CarouselView` which consists of collection Card controls described inside `DataTemplate` I need to find that particular active control only, let's say `Label` that I want to animate. Not sure how to find it, there are one instance of it per each item in VM collection, but even if I do it does not look to be a good MVVM oriented design.
- My big hope was on `TriggerAction<Label>` (given I want to animate `Label`), but then problem is TriggerAction seems to only work inside `EventTrigger` which only catches **xaml control** events, not VM events. What can catch VM events and property changes is `DataTrigger`, but it does not allow to have `TriggerAction<T>` declared inside on the other hand. Not sure why there is such limitation in .Net Maui, I wish I had some mix of both.
- Behaviors, - as with triggers not sure how to run them by any property change or event declared in VM

```cs
// ViewModel (mvvm community toolkit is used):
    public partial class CollectionOfItems : ObservableObject
    {
       public Item[] Items {get; set;}
    }
    
    public partial class Item : ObservableObject
    {
       [ObservableProperty]
       public string _name;
    
       // Setting this to false should trigger Label animation
       [ObservableProperty]
       public bool _isInvalid;
    }
```

```xml
    ...
    <CarouselView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
       <CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
            <Label Text="{Binding Name}">
                   <Label.Triggers>
                      <DataTrigger TargetType="Label" Binding="{Binding IsInvalid}" Value="True">
<!-- I wish I was able to trigger InvalidDataTriggerAction from here, but it's not compatible with DataTrigger -->
                      </DataTrigger>
                   </Label.Triggers>
            </Label>
         </DataTemplate>
       </CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
    </CarouselView>
    ...
```

```cs
    // Animation should be implemented in c#, not XAML
    // Should be triggered by IsInvalid=false, but I do not know how:   
    public class InvalidDataTriggerAction : TriggerAction<Label>
    {
        protected override void Invoke(Label label)
        {
            label.TranslateTo(-30, 0, 100);
            label.TranslateTo(60, 0, 100);
            label.TranslateTo(-30, 0, 100);
        }
    }
```

Comment: **Add to question** the code you have now, that needs to be modified to accomplish this. You mention a `CarouselView`, a `Template` and a `ViewModel`; add xaml and cs that shows how these are defined and connected. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I have added simplistic version of the code, though it's very basic, nothing special, not sure if it helps you

Answer (score 3):

Alright, I've found a way to do it through bindable properties inside behaviors. Happened to be bit more complicated than I expected, but it works. Unfortunately .NET Maui does not provide a better more intuitive way to do that, I guess it's the area for improvement.

Here's the code:

```
namespace View.Behaviors;

public class AnimateWrongAnswerBehavior : BaseBehavior<VisualElement>
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty ShouldAnimateProperty =
        BindableProperty.CreateAttached(
            "ShouldAnimate",
            typeof(bool),
            typeof(AnimateWrongAnswerBehavior),
            false,
            propertyChanged: OnShouldAnimateChanged);

    public static void SetShouldAnimate(BindableObject view, VisualElement value) =>
        view.SetValue(ShouldAnimateProperty, value);

    static async void OnShouldAnimateChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
    {
        if ((bool)newValue)
        {
            await Animate((VisualElement)bindable);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Implemenation of Animation logic
    /// </summary>  
    static private async Task Animate(VisualElement elementToAnimate)
    {
        await elementToAnimate.TranslateTo(-30, 0, 100);
        await elementToAnimate.TranslateTo(60, 0, 100);
        await elementToAnimate.TranslateTo(-30, 0, 100);
    }
}
```

Then you can bind animation to any visual element like `Frame`:

```
<ContentPage 
   xmlns:bh="clr-namespace:View.Behaviors" ...>

    <Frame bh:AnimateWrongAnswerBehavior.ShouldAnimate="{Binding IsInvalid}">

</ContentPage>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just like you said, the control in the datatemplate is hard to access. So I have done a sample to test the `TranslateX` property of the Label. And I found that `label.TranslateTo(60, 0, 100);` had the same effect as the `label.TranslateX = 60`.

According to this, you can create a variable in the Item and binding it to the label in the DataTemplate. And change the item's value in the page.cs. And you can also use the `DataTrigger` to set the value of label.TranslateX.

Comment: thank you for your answer, @Liyun. While it would work for the "translate" type of animation, it won't for more complex. That's why one of the requirement I listed was in-code animation. Also I'm not sure if it's a good from mvvm design standpoint, to have some property representing TranslateX value being part of your model, along with like person name. Nevertheless I upvoted your answer is it's an interesting solution, definitely workaround for some similar cases.

Comment: I'm sorry for that I can't find any other way to do this without data binding. And all the similar cases I can found told me to use binding to set the control in the datatemplate in the xamarin. Because you want to set it when the viewmodel's property changed not a event, it seems impossible to do that in other ways. Thanks for you upvoting. @YMC

Comment: viewmodel's event is fine, it's even mentioned in my question `by any property change or event`. I thought about declaring event in ViewModel and raise it in ViewModel, and codebehind can subscribe for it, but then the issue I'm facing is how to get proper (active) control to animate out of many existing instances of it inside DataTemplate

Comment: But it seems there is no way to get the instance of the control in the datatemplate in the xamarin and maui. @YMC

Answer (score 1):

Please note that `TranslateTo` is awaitable and might need the `async`/`await` pattern for the element to be animated, especially if more than one `TranslateTo` is invoked.

`TriggerAction` with `async`/`await` added:

```
public class TriggerActionTranslateTo : TriggerAction<VisualElement>
{
  protected override async void Invoke(VisualElement sender)
  {
      await sender.TranslateTo(0, 0, 250);
      await sender.TranslateTo(30, 0, 250);
      await sender.TranslateTo(0, 0, 250);
  }
```

For some reason `async`/`await` is not needed with only one `TranslateTo` and this will animate:

```
protected override void Invoke(VisualElement sender)
{
    sender.TranslateTo(30, 0, 250);
}
```

XAML:

```
<Label.Triggers>
  <DataTrigger
    TargetType="Label"
    Binding="{Binding Property}" 
    Value="True">
  <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
    <ns:TriggerActionTranslateTo/>
  </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
  <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
  ...
```

Comment: it's awaited in my response